# Link one record to multiple records in separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

### Background Info

I have a database with two tables: `Phones`, and `Carriers`

Phones -> Carriers

`Phones` (Primary key: `Phones.ID`; Foreign Key: `Phones.CarrierID`) is linked to

`Carriers` (Primary key: `Carriers.ID`; Foreign Key: `Carriers.RegionID`).

The data types for both `Phones.CarrierID` and `Carriers.ID` are bigint. *Sorry if that's confusing!*

### Problem

I have a record in my Phones table called Nokia Lumia 1020. I need to be able to link it to multiple records in the Carriers Table via the `Phones.CarrierID` column. How would I do this without creating multiple records for the Nokia Lumia 1020 in the `Phones` table?

Comment: What do you mean by link.  You've linked them with your Foeign Key. Do you want a select statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Many-to-Many relationship.  Typically this is implemented by adding a table in between the two data tables:

```
Phones -> PhoneCarriers -> Carriers
```

`PhoneCarrier` will look something like:

```
PhoneCarrierID
PhoneID (FK)
CarrierID (FK)
```

You won't have a foreign key directly from `Phone` to `Carrier` in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to SQL and Databases!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a PhoneCarriers table:

```
PhoneCarriers
-------------
PhoneCarrierID <-- Unimportant PK
PhoneID        <-- FK to Phones Table
CarrierID      <-- FK to Carrier Table.
```

This is where your multiple entries exist.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `Phones.CarrierID` column. Then create a third table `CarriersToPhones` which has two columns: `Phones.ID` and `Carriers.ID`. Be sure to create a composite primary or unique key with those two columns.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have mentioned already, you need a table to store the relationships between phones and carriers.  I've created a test schema that illustrates this:

```
USE Test;

CREATE TABLE Phones 
(
    PhoneID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Phones_PhoneID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , PhoneName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Carriers
(
    CarrierID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Carriers_CarrierID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CarrierName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PhonesCarriersXRef
(
    PhoneID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_PhonesCarriersXRef_Phones_PhoneID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Phones (PhoneID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    , CarrierID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_PhonesCarriersXRef_Carriers_CarrierID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Carriers (CarrierID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    CONSTRAINT PK_PhonesCarriersXRef PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PhoneID, CarrierID)
);

INSERT INTO Phones (PhoneName) VALUES ('Nokia Lumia 1020');
INSERT INTO Phones (PhoneName) VALUES ('Nokia Lumia 920');

INSERT INTO Carriers (CarrierName) VALUES ('AT&T');
INSERT INTO Carriers (CarrierName) VALUES ('Verizon');

INSERT INTO PhonesCarriersXRef (PhoneID, CarrierID) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO PhonesCarriersXRef (PhoneID, CarrierID) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO PhonesCarriersXRef (PhoneID, CarrierID) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO PhonesCarriersXRef (PhoneID, CarrierID) VALUES (2,2);

SELECT C.CarrierName, P.PhoneName
FROM PhonesCarriersXRef X
    INNER JOIN Phones P ON X.PhoneID = P.PhoneID
    INNER JOIN Carriers C ON X.CarrierID = C.CarrierID
ORDER BY C.CarrierName, P.PhoneName;
```

This returns the following:

[image]

Comment: WOW! Thanks a bunch! This was going to be one of my next questions! lol